# fsevents is not a function while running initial test on React-Testing-Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am new to React-Testing-Library and I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: fsevents is not a function
>
> ```
> at new FSEventsWatcher (/Users/abc/Desktop/PostIt/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/lib/FSEventsWatcher.js:162:20)
> at createWatcher (/Users/abc/Desktop/PostIt/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:1052:23)
> at Array.map (<anonymous>)
> at HasteMap._watch (/Users/abc/Desktop/PostIt/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:1230:44)
> at /Users/abc/Desktop/PostIt/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:517:21
> at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
> at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/abc/Desktop/PostIt/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:193:24)
> at _next (/Users/abc/Desktop/PostIt/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:213:9)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm
> ```
>
> ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! post@0.1.0 test: `react-scripts test` npm ERR!
>   Exit status 1 npm ERR! Failed at the post@0.1.0 test script. npm ERR!
>   This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
>   logging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found
>   in:

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, waitForElement, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
afterEach(cleanup)

test('make sure that I can submit a question', async () => {
  const {debug} = render(
    <App />
  ) 
debug();
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and do `npm install` again.